# How to announce changes of superclass properties to subclasses?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code in my app which was tested on a playground so the code below runs from top to bottom. The superclass's duration property is correctly set to 222 seconds but the subclass is not able to get that value. How do I send the change to the subclass?

```
import SwiftUI

class AudioPlaybackManager {
    @Published var duration = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print(duration) //prints 222
        }
    }
    
    func loadSong() {
        //duration is 222 seconds
        duration = 222
    }
}

let audio = AudioPlaybackManager()
audio.loadSong()

class Scrubber: AudioPlaybackManager {
    @Published var scrubberValue = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print(duration) //prints 0 instead of 222
        }
    }
}

let scrubber = Scrubber()
scrubber.scrubberValue = 1
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept. Imagine 2 people(superclass) named audio and scrubber. Both people are independent from each other. They don’t know what the other does unless something is creating a connection. You need that connection. You can create a variable in scrubber that uses .sink to keep track of what audio is doing. But as they are they are now both are just two people/AudioPlaybackManager with no communication between them.

Comment: It’s call inheritance because they inherit their traits (variables, functions, etc) like a child does from their parents but ultimately there two different objects with no connection.

Answer (score 0):

While `Scrubber` is a subclass of `AudioPlaybackManager`,  `scrubber` and `audio` are independent objects.

Therefore, when you create `scrubber`, its `duration` is 0, and since you don't change it, you get the result you have.  Works as designed.

It would perfectly well work if you would change scrubber's duration, by calling loadSong():

```
let scrubber = Scrubber()
scrubber.loadSong()                      // prints 222
scrubber.scrubberValue = 1               // prints 222
```

Comment: I have a AVPlayer in the superclass and I need to get the duration of that AVPlayer from my subclass during runtime. Is there any elegant way to do it?